# How to check if any activity is currently opened or not

Tags: android, android-activity

In my android application from my background service I want to launch activity with transparent background. Because of the fact that the application is transparent I always want it to be displayed on some other activity from my application. So before the launch I would need to somehow check if any activity is currently opened and if it isn't then open home activity and after that my transparent activity. But if application was already opened then I want to open new activity on top of most recent one.

How could I achieve that? Only thing I found is how to check if my application is in foreground or not. But when my app is in background I would still like to open my transparent activity atop most recent activity.

Comment: `my background service I want to launch activity` Starting with Android Q this is now illegal. `I always want it to be displayed on some other activity from my application` There can only be 1 Activity active at all time.

Comment: Why would you want a transparent activity? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You can use -EventBus- library to pass data between activities. Check this link. Using EventBus you can check them easily. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WnzSkRinnuc

Comment: for get activity top on the screen, you should be implemented activityLifeCycle

Answer (score 0):

```
class FirebaseDbApplication : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
    }

    companion object{

        private var sIsChatActivityOpen = false

        fun isChatActivityOpen() : Boolean {
            return sIsChatActivityOpen
        }

        fun setChatActivityOpen(isChatActivityOpen: Boolean) {
            this.sIsChatActivityOpen = isChatActivityOpen
        }

    }
}
```

// In your activity

```
 override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        FirebaseDbApplication.setChatActivityOpen(true)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        FirebaseDbApplication.setChatActivityOpen(false)
    }
```

// For checking is activity is opened or not

```
if (FirebaseDbApplication.isChatActivityOpen()) {
   // Activity is opened 
}
else{
   // Activity is closed
}
```